# What is the meaning of "...the cost of a 5 year R01..."?

Tags: funding, united-states

I assume this is something  related to the US and  NIH Research Project Grant Program (R01), but I don't understand how one put value on a "single  word"
Is there anyone who understands this sentence and care to elaborate what was implied by that?
[image]

Answer (score 12):

According to [the yearly NIH report](https://report.nih.gov/success_rates/Success_ByIC_Details.cfm?IC=NIAID), in 2018, a total of 625 NIH Research Project grants (R01) were awarded, and the total cost for NIH (funding + other costs) of these grants was $347,466,328. This averages to $347,466,328/625, or about **$556,000** of funding per year in one grant, or **$2,780,000 in total for a 5-year grant**

The *Specific Aims* application document [is considered](https://www.biosciencewriters.com/NIH-Grant-Applications-The-Anatomy-of-a-Specific-Aims-Page.aspx) to be (one of) the most important part(s) of the application. The example document on that website has 601 words. The tweet in your question exaggerates the importance of the Specific Aims document, and implies that the document is "worth" the whole $2,780,000 of the grant. The cost of each word would then be $2,780,000/600, or approximately **$4633 per word**.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. but arent R01 grants for basic and expensive research?

Comment: I guess the tweet just wants to highlight how stressful it is to write a document when you know that every word you write might be worth $4000 **if** you write them well enough.

Comment: Isn't it more stressful not to have grant?

Comment: Exactly, that is why you had better write a **very good document**. Otherwise, the next 5 years are gonna be hard. See what I mean? There is a lot at stake in a 600-word document.

Comment: @SSimon R01s can fund basic, translational and clinical research. As for the expense, some studies are expensive, others are less expensive, but very few, if any, will be for small cheap projects.

Comment: @StrongBad so why shock and astonishment ower that?

Comment: @SSimon It's just a tweet, meant for people who have worked on these sorts of grants. If it doesn't speak to you, you don't have to like or retweet it.

Comment: @SSimon Nobody's "shocked" or "astonished". It's just harrowing is all. You can probably just move on

Answer (score 5):

R01s are the main grants given by the US NIH to research labs. They typically have a single PI but can have some other co-PIs, and depending on scope are worth a few hundred thousand USD per year over five years.

The "specific aims page" is a 1-page summary of the goals of the grant, kind of like an abstract. So, this tweet is connecting A) the words on 1 page of paper in a grant to B) the total value of that grant over 5 years. ($3000 to $4000) * maybe 500 words = $1.5 - $2.0 million over 5 years, $300-$400k per year.

There's nothing particularly insightful about it, although writing a specific aims page is a pretty time consuming part of writing one of these grants, since the space is so limited.

Comment: interesting, why would she connected those two things? why is important

Comment: @SSimon I can only guess, but that's what I try to do in the last sentence of my answer. It's an important part of a grant application, so I suppose the difference between writing 500 good words and 500 bad ones is the value of the grant. Again, I don't think it's particularly insightful or anything, it's just making a statement about how the value of a grant compares to the actual document used to apply for one (though, just one piece of it; a full R01 grant application is many pages long).

Comment: I guess for comparison, my answer here took 135 words, the largest amount of money I expect to make out of it is $0, so that comes out to about $0 per word. Much less stressful to write this answer than to write a specific aims page where each word could be worth $4000.

Comment: Well you got upvote, which values for 10 points which values for personal satisfaction and those things are priceless. On the other hand having NO grant or funding is so much more stressful

Comment: When you look at the numbers this way, even expanding it to all 5000 words of the grant, it surprises me we don't pay at least for copy editors.

Comment: can one put a price on knowledge and new findings generated from successful grant